react gh-pages -d deploy gives error: Error: spawn git ENOENT at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19) at onErrorNT
when i using npm run deploy command i get error
error is:

Error: spawn git ENOENT
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) Emitted 'error' event on
ChildProcess instance at:
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:476:16)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {   errno: -4058,   code:
'ENOENT',   syscall: 'spawn git',   path: 'git',   spawnargs: [
'config', 'user.name' ] }

code :
    {
  "homepage": "http://mertciril.github.io/react-project",
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test", 
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^6.2.0"
  }
}

